# Math mode questions on font size

Tags: math-mode, amsmath

I've been using `$$ \nabla $$` on StackExchange to inline multiple math equations with success.  I'm switching to pure Latex using Overleaf and have questions.

My goal is to produce a document with some simple left aligned or centered equations.  I try the following code, however it has problems:

1. Font size too small of math equations, changing \documentclass[Xpt]{article} has no effect on math equation font size
2. Spacing between each equation line is too small.  I want to increase the spacing

Can anyone provide suggestions here?  I provide some sample code I'm working with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % Required for inserting images
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{math}
     C_x(...) = \sum_{j=0}^{n_L - 1} (a_j^{(L)} - y_j)^2 \\
     a_j^{(L)} = \sigma(z_j^{(L)}), z_j^{(L)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n_L - 1} (w_{jk}^{(L)} a_k^{(L-1)}) + b_j^{(L)} \\
\end{math}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.se, try `\begin{align}` instead maybe?

Comment: 1 is incorrect. The three options 10pt, 11pt and 12pt all affect math as well as text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you display the equations across three lines, rather than just two. To increase the vertical spacing between the rows, append `[\jot]` to `\\`.

A suggestion about notation (*not* implemented in the code below): Would it be ok to replace all instances of `(L)` and `(L-1)` with just `L` and `L-1`, respectively? Making this change would greatly reduce the high degree of visual clutter.

The code shown below doesn't specify a font size option when executing the `\documentclass` directive, implying that the default `10pt` document font size is employed. If you choose to set `12pt` as one of the document class options, the text *and* math fonts will be increased linearly by 20 percent relative to the default 10pt option.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for `align*` env.

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
C_x({}\cdot{}) &= \sum_{j=0}^{n_L - 1} \bigl(a_j^{(L)} - y_j \bigr)^2 \\[\jot]
     a_j^{(L)} &= \sigma\bigl(z_j^{(L)}\bigr) \\[\jot]
     z_j^{(L)} &= \sum_{k=0}^{n_L - 1} w_{jk}^{(L)} a_k^{(L-1)} + b_j^{(L)} 
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I wasn't aware of `[\jot]` option. I use  something like `[1mm]` instead of that. It seems that `[\jot]` is standard and automated. Can you explain its logic?

Comment: @C.F.G - `\jot` is a length parameter that's defined by the `amsmath` package. Its default value is `3pt`. Not sure what you mean by `[\jot]` being "automated"; for sure, if no optional parameter is provided to the `\\` line-break directive, then nothing special happens. An advantage to specifying `\jot` in terms of a standard typographic length (such as `pt`) instead of `mm` is that its easier to gauge its effect on the appearance of the math formula.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{align}
     C_x(...) &= \sum_{j=0}^{n_L - 1} (a_j^{(L)} - y_j)^2 \\
     a_j^{(L)} &= \sigma(z_j^{(L)}), z_j^{(L)} = \sum_{k=0}^{n_L - 1} (w_{jk}^{(L)} a_k^{(L-1)}) + b_j^{(L)} 
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

Using `align` environment lets you use `&=` instead of just `=`, the ampersand (`&`) makes the equations align at that symbol. The spacing is improved of your original code but perhaps might not be enough, if so please comment.

Comment: `\DeclareMathSizes{10}{14}{10}{10}` is a _very_ odd setting.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm not too familiar with having to set math fonts, what would be more appropriate do you think? I have a feeling the last `{10}` is odd because it is scriptscript size

Comment: yes you are making script and scriptscript the same size, but I suspect the answer is simply to delete that.  The original comment about math being small was most likely because `\sum` was set in inline style which you already fixed using `align`. 14pt math in a 10pt running text will make inline math unusable even if it is just about OK in display math.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ah right, I understand, I didn't know that about sum! Thanks for the feedback, I have removed reference to `\DeclareMathSizes` and will await feedback from the OP if they need further change